# Clicked table row bound via knockoutjs gets not selected

Tags: knockout.js

I want to make a simple table row selectable by clicking on it just like here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/APzK8/6/

I applied the above logic but still nothing is selected, what do I wrong?

The data is displayed correctly, just the selecting does not work.

```
define(['services/dataservice'], function (dataservice) {

    var self = this;
    this.Selected = ko.observable();
    var schoolyears = ko.observableArray();

    this.SelectSchoolyear = function (config) {
        self.Selected(config);
    };

    this.Selected(schoolyears()[0]);

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        schoolyears: schoolyears,
        title: 'Schoolyears'
        };
    return vm;

    function activate(){
        var schoolyearModels = dataservice.getSchoolyears();
        var schoolyearViewModels = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < schoolyearModels.length; i++){
            var e = schoolyearModels[i];
            var schoolyearViewModel = new SchoolyearViewModel(e.schoolyearId, e.schoolyearName, e.from, e.to, e.lastEdited, self.Selected);
            schoolyearViewModels.push(schoolyearViewModel);
        }
        return schoolyears(schoolyearViewModels);
    }
    function SchoolyearViewModel(id, schoolyearName, from, to, lastEdited, selected){
        var me = this;
        this.schoolyearId = id;
        this.schoolyearName = ko.observable(schoolyearName);
        this.from = ko.observable(from);
        this.to = ko.observable(to);
        this.lastEdited = ko.observable(lastEdited);
        this.AmISelected = ko.computed(function (){
            debugger;
            return selected() === me;
        });
    }  

});


<section id="schoolyears-view" class="view">
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-force-refresh pull-right" data-bind="click: remove" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i>Delete</a>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 25%">Schoolyear name</th>
                <th style="width: 25%">From</th>
                <th style="width: 25%">To</th>
                <th style="width: 250%">Last edited</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: schoolyears">
            <tr data-bind="click: $parent.SelectSchoolyear, css: { selected: AmISelected }, attr: { 'data-id': schoolyearId }" >
                <td data-bind="text: schoolyearName()"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: from()"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: to()"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: lastEdited()"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that Knockout is looking for the `remove` and `SelectSchoolyear` methods on the `vm` object, but they aren't present. They're only on the `this` object.

Here's a solution (note that you still need an implementation for `remove`):

```
var vm = {
   activate: activate,
   schoolyears: schoolyears,
   title: 'Schoolyears',
   SelectSchoolyear: self.SelectSchoolyear,
   remove: function () {}
};
```

This assumes that `activate` is called somewhere.

```
vm.activate();
```

I've made a working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X4CM5/2/).

Note: To view binding errors (like the ones I mentioned), just use your browser's developer console (Knockout will throw exceptions).

Comment: argh.... because of the missing things like remove that was a copy/paste problem... I just wanted to post the important stuff. Just 5 min before I read your solution I thought hm... the schoolyears are bound but something is missing :P the SelectSchoolyear property... Thanks dude that made it working. Really thanks.

Comment: funny your jsfiddle works fine I can select every row, but in my code I can select only every 2nd row ??? When I remove this bootstrap class from the table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"> (in short I have no alternating rows) then my sample works too ok thats another SO question...